# Spring OAUTH: Override CheckTokenEndpoint 'check_token?token=' response map

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, oauth, spring-security-oauth2

I would like to override the CheckTokenEndpoint to provide my own custom output as Map to the resource server. I have tried the following, but not working.

1. Introducing new custom controller for (/oauth/check_token), but Spring rejects this custom and registers its own.

> Overriding bean definition for bean 'checkTokenEndpoint' with a
>   different definition: replacing [Generic bean: class
>   [com.datami.auth.security.CheckTokenEndpoint]; scope=singleton;
>   abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0;
>   autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null;
>   factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null;
>   defined in file
>   [/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/8.5.5/libexec/webapps/oauth-server/WEB-INF/classes/com/datami/auth/security/CheckTokenEndpoint.class]]
>   with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false;
>   autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true;
>   primary=false;
>   factoryBeanName=org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfiguration;
>   factoryMethodName=checkTokenEndpoint; initMethodName=null;
>   destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/security/oauth2/config/annotation/web/configuration/AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfiguration.class]]

2. Created my own endpoint with (`/oauth/check_custom_token`) but not sure autowiring resourceServerTokenServices in the below, @autowire doesn't helped me.

   @autowire 
   private ResourceServerTokenServices resourceServerTokenServices;

Spring has autowired this with `DefaultTokenServices`.

I can also create `new DefaultTokenServices()` in my code, but then how to autowire the below inside DefaultTokenServices? again the same problem.

```
private TokenStore tokenStore;

private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

private TokenEnhancer accessTokenEnhancer;

private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
```

Coul you please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CheckTokenEndpoint` depends on its `accessTokenConverter` instance to create and return the map.

You could create a custom AccessTokenConverter (maybe extending from OOTB `DefaultAccessTokenConverter` if needed) and use it like so:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class MyAuthConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    ...

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.accessTokenConverter(new MyAccessTokenConverter())...

        ....
```

Of course, you might want to use a factory method to create your accessTokenConverter instance, which allows you to inject a few properties into the instance etc.

Once done, inside `AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfiguration.checkTokenEndpoint` you can see that the accessTokenConverter you set above will be passed to the OOTB instance of `CheckTokenEndpoint` and used to create the map.